# How to move sharepoint document library from one server to another server preserving all the versions

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to move a share point document library from one server to another server. 
I want all the versions to be preserved cant afford to loose the versions.
Is there a way without any server side coding, i don't have access to the destination server. i am site collection admin only.

I am Administrator on the source server and Farm Admin.
I am Site collection admin on the destination Site.
Have to move Document library from source server to Destination Server Site without losing all the versions.

I am using MOSS 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Versions web service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/versions.versions(v=office.12).aspx) will allow you to retrieve the old versions of a file in SharePoint.  If you then work from oldest to newest, you should be able to apply them to the new site and maintain all the versions.